# MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED not called when decoding h.264 in some devices

Tags: android, h.264, decoder, android-mediacodec

I'm using the following code to prepare the hardware decoder. I expect outputBufferIndex to be -1 and then followed by MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED. It shouldn't >=0 before notifying format changed.

I tested the code in 25 different devices, and 7 of them never return INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED. mediaCodec.getOutputFormat() returned IllegalStateException when I got outputBufferIndex >= 0. I have no idea if it was a coincidence that all devices did't work were android 4.2.2 with OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc decoder.

```
for (int i = 0; i < videoExtractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(i);
    String mime = mediaFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
    if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
        videoExtractor.selectTrack(i);
        videoCodec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mediaFormat.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME));
        videoCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, 0);
        videoCodec.start();
    }
}
ByteBuffer[] videoInputBuffers = videoCodec.getInputBuffers();
while (true) {
    int sampleTrackIndex = videoExtractor.getSampleTrackIndex();
    if (sampleTrackIndex == -1) {
        break;
    } else { // decode video
        int inputBufferIndex = videoCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(0);
        if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            int bytesRead = videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoInputBuffers[inputBufferIndex], 0);
            if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                videoCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, bytesRead,
                        videoExtractor.getSampleTime(), 0);
                videoExtractor.advance();
            }
        }
        MediaCodec.BufferInfo videoBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
        int outputBufferIndex = videoCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(videoBufferInfo, 0);
        if (outputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            MediaFormat format = videoCodec.getOutputFormat();
            Log.w("video format changed: " + videoCodec.getOutputFormat());
            //do something...
            break;
        } else if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {
            //not supposed to happen!
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for the clues and helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Android 4.3, a collection of `MediaCodec` tests were added to CTS.  If you look at the way `doEncodeDecodeVideoFromBuffer()` works in [EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest), you can see that it expects the `INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED` result before any data.  If it doesn't get it, the call to `checkFrame()` will fail when it tries to get the color format.  Prior to Android 4.3, there were no tests, and any behavior is possible.

Having said that, I don't recall seeing this behavior on the (Qualcomm-based) Nexus 4.

At any rate, I'm not sure how much this will actually hold you back, unless you're able to decode the proprietary buffer layout Qualcomm uses.  You can see in that same `checkFrame()` function that it punts when it sees `OMX_QCOM_COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar64x32Tile2m8ka`.  Sending the output to a Surface may be a viable alternative depending on what you're up to.

Most of the `MediaCodec` code on [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/) and in [Grafika](http://github.com/google/grafika) targets API 18 (Android 4.3), because that's when the behavior became more predictable.  (The availability of surface input and `MediaMuxer` is also of tremendous value.)

Comment: Yes, I did put a lot of effort converting proprietary yuv format like QCOM_COLOR_FormatYUV420XXX and COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420XXX to I420. It was not only INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED not called, but mediaFormat was not updated when outputBufferIndex >=0. Even worse, program hangs when I releaseOutputBuffer. I tried google's software codec, and it hangs when I do MediaCodec.configure on these devices, while it works perfectly on the others. I checked csd-0 and csd-1, which were correct.